# Is Visual Basic 6 still widely used?

Tags: vb6

Are there still enough VB6 shops to make learning the language worthwhile?

Comment: Depends on what you need it for? Why would you *want* to learn it?

Comment: No. Learn any other language.

Comment: @Konrad. Microsoft [said](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/funkyonex/What-is-Microsofts-Visual-Basic-6-Support-Strategy/) in September 2009 that there were still several million people using VB6. At my company we still use VB6 every day. So may I suggest instead: *Yes - but still I advise you to learn any other modern language*

Comment: I'd suggest looking at it another way.  There are plenty of highly experienced VB6 programmers in the market to meet the needs of existing employers.  This probably makes the cost/benefit ratio bad for anyone starting out at this late date.  The only exception might be in specialized fields where VB6 is still popular but other less-widely held skills are also needed.

Comment: @Bob, good point. And the experienced VB6 programmers are not that old (are we?), so you'd have a lot of stiff competition for a long time to come.

Comment: @Bob @John +1 Bob's comment should be the accepted answer! We still have a lot of VB6 code here, but when we're recruiting we don't look for VB6 skills particularly. We reckon those of us with greying hair can easily help bright new hires get to grips with VB6, provided they can program.

Comment: My answer is YES, but I would recommend learning VB.NET if you can (instead of VB6), and if you want to learn C# (just enough to read other peoples code examples) that is ok too, but I would recommend you code in VB.NET since it is considerably more enjoyable than coding in c#, + you get many things in VB.NET that you will never get in c# (unfortunately), and these things out number the things you get in c# that you can't get in VB.NET CONSIDERABLY. If I had to choose between VB6 and c#, i'd choose c#, but choosing between VB.NET & c#, i would choose and totally recommend you choose VB.NET.

Answer (score 12):

I work for a fortune 25 company and we have a few legacy apps there were written in VB6.  However all new development (in the Windows world) is strictly .NET.  I would suggest learning VB.NET if you're interested in learning VB.

Answer (score 11):

Computing languages don't die easily, and there are always niche markets where those skills are needed.  Languages like Smalltalk, Lisp, COBOL, etc. have there loyal followers and clients that need those abilities.  There will probably be some need for VB6 for a while yet.

The chief difference between VB6 and the other languages I mentioned is that the newer version of VB (VB.Net) has been declared by Microsoft to replace VB6.  That tells me that VB6 will have a shrinking market as newer versions of Windows makes it near impossible to have VB6 apps that look like current modern applications.

My advice is: if you have a current need for VB6, like maintaining a legacy application, by all means learn it.  The more useful you are to a company, the longer they'll keep you.  If you don't have a current need for VB6 then learn the newer version of the technology.  In the Microsoft world, the .NET CLR based languages are the current vision of the future.  You'll also have more success finding help for problems you're facing day to day.

Comment: +1 Microsoft [said](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/funkyonex/What-is-Microsofts-Visual-Basic-6-Support-Strategy/) in September 09 that there were still several million people using VB6. Microsoft are still [fully supporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708.aspx) the VB6 runtime.

Comment: +1 for using the phrase 'current vision of the future'

Comment: Now 7 years later, you can't run VB6 apps on current versions of Windows.  With the death (official end of support) of XP a lot of legacy support also ended.

Answer (score 10):

I **do not think** it is **worth to learn** VB6.

I work for company where main product is written in VB6 and know one another company where main product is written in VB6 too.

In both cases:

1. All **new products**/development is **done in .NET** (mainly **VB.NET** to keep syntax similar).
2. **None of developers** know VB6 when joined company.

In other words:

**VB6** is probably still **widely used**, but companies **migrate** to VB.NET. Moreover **VB6 is so easy** to learn that you can start using it really fast **with no** previous **experience**.

Answer (score 3):

I also work an Fortune 25 company with a world-wide presence and many legacy VB6 apps are still widely used through the company.  Myself, I am a .NET developer and only learn as much VB6 as I need to fix a production issue or to convert something to .NET (typically C#).  So no, don't invest time in learning it unless you must on the job.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use vb too often - I know a lot of larger businesses (Insurance, IT you name it) who do use VB functions so managers can input data into their DB's through some kind of 'Excel' sheet.

Learning any language is worthwhile! VB is easy to understand and M$ has many libraries that are easy to use (i.e. look at connecting to Databases/creating Forms... if you're interested in what real world applications are built on it).

I've used it once for the SOAP api (very easy), and some other applications. I thought it was nice enough.

Comment: are you talking about VB6 or VB.NET? What you're saying seems to apply to VB.NET.

Comment: It actually sounds more like VB script.

Comment: Or VBA maybe? As in Excel macros?

Comment: sorry yes, vba wasn't paying attention

Comment: VBA is practically 95% of VB6, so learning either give you more capabilities than people usually think. There is so much VBA embedded in Excel and Word, plus so many VB6 apps.

Answer (score 1):

There are still companies using VB6. Where I'm active for example. But we're migrating to .NET. (the sooner the better in my opinion)

So, as mentioned by aioobe, why would you want to learn VB6? I'd say it's a waste of time and I would spend my time in, for example, VB.NET. 
Unless you have a really good argument for VB6 ofcourse.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt waste my time learning VB6. I worked with it 10 years ago and I'm still thankful everytime I look at my CV that I had the opportunity to start working in C#.NET. VB6 felt like a mickey mouse language.

Comment: why would you opt for c# (no background compiler, mandatory ; at end of every line, case sensitive [ugh], and so many things that take the enjoyment out of programming)... when you could have easily converted to the beauty of the vb.net language. i only learnt c# so i could read peoples code examples, but i only code in vb.net and vb6 when i have to.

Answer (score 1):

You might do a search on indeed.com for "VB6" and draw your own conclusions.  I find about 900 jobs there as opposed to 112,000 jobs on a search for ".net".

Answer (score 0):

There are still products around that are written in it (I have two myself) but Microsoft have meant to have said that Windows 8 will not work with VB6 programs, also Visual Studio 6 (required to build VB6 projects) does not easily run on Vista and Win7.

VBA is very similar in syntax and it looks like this will be supported for the next few years at least.

My advice: learn VBA if you need it, but only learn VB6 if you have a maintenance project that requires it. If you really want to learn BASIC then go for VB.NET. It is difficult to suggest other alternatives (there are lots!) unless we know about what you want to learn and why. Eg. If you wanted to learn about OOP then I think C# or Java would be better.

Comment: VB.NET and C# are basically the same (except the syntax). There are some small differences which were caused by the 'release-competition' by both the VB- and the C#-team. But Microsoft already said that in the future VB.NET and C# will be equal. Although C# is considered the main .NET language (also by Microsoft itself).

Comment: @Rhapsody: They've said that for awhile now.  I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: @Rhapsody: the last sentence is just not true. It might be, in the future, but now now. In fact, I’ve even heard Microsoft employees say the opposite (i.e. that VB is the main language) … but that was a few years ago.

Comment: @Konrad - I worked for Microsoft for about 2 years 2007-2009, VB was always thrid or fourth choice for us a development platform, it is true that VB was the main language in early implementations of .NET 2003, but with the rapid growth of C# and it usage, C# is now the main language in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

**Google**

1. VB6 - About 5,080,000 Results
2. Visual Basic 6 - About 33,700,000
   Results
3. VB.NET - About 35,200,000 Results
4. Visual Basic .NET - About 20,800,000
   Results

**StackOverFlow**

1. vb6 - 1920

VB6 applications are probably still used quite a lot but I believe for new development over the years VB6 has been chosen less and less as a primary platform to develop an application with people opting for .NET alternatives.

In terms of learning it, I would only do this is you need to work with old VB6 applications that will not be upgraded to .NET, or if you are upgrading VB6 applications to .NET then by all means learn it but dont waste to much time on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard an educated guess, based on my own experience, that there are many more programmers writing new COBOL programs than new VB6 programs. VB6 is ten years replaced <strike>and, as far as I can tell, no longer supported in any way by Microsoft</strike>.

Comment: Microsoft [said](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/funkyonex/What-is-Microsofts-Visual-Basic-6-Support-Strategy/) in September 09 that there were still several million people using VB6. Microsoft are still [fully supporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708.aspx) the VB6 runtime.

Comment: @MarkJ, thanks for the correction. I stand by my assertion there are more people writing new COBOL programs than new VB6.